# Obtain user email domain in Azure AD B2C through Graph API

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, identity

I'm trying to prevent to register more than one user in my app with the same email domain.

So, I'm creating a custom policy on AD B2C to connect with the Azure Function that checks through Graph API if the domain exists on the tenant.

I'm trying to use this approach:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .Filter("identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId eq 'j.smith@yahoo.com' and c/issuer eq 'My B2C tenant')")
    .Select("displayName,id")
    .GetAsync();
```

The problem is that I cannot change the `eq` value to `contains` to filter by domain, and `endsWith` functions do not work in AD B2C tenants.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by matching the whole content in StartsWith()

```
var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .Filter("startswith(identities/issuerAssignedId,'j.smith@yahoo.com')")
    .Select("displayName,id")
    .GetAsync();
```

please see the official doc for more info - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-2